# Run multiple functions simultaneously python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a script which will search a CSV file. If the row in the CSV meets a certain condition it will run a `while True: loop`, i.e. it will never end. I, however, want to run this function for multiple rows of the CSV at the same time.

```
with open('list.csv', "rt") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['Name'] == "x":
                doSomething()
            else:
                print("Not available")
```

This current code works, for example, if the first row is `x` it will run the function correctly. If the first row isn't `x` but the second row is then it will print `not available` and then run the function for the second row.
I want it so if the first row is `x` it will `doSomething()`, then if the second row is also `x` it will `doSomething()` again at the same time.

I have not seen a way of doing this.

I think it needs to use threading, however, each thread needs to pass to the next row in the CSV.
e.g. first time running the function use the first row of the CSV
second time use the second row
third time use the third-row etc.
repeat n times for n rows in CSV

Comment: Start a thread for `doSomething` on each row. Look into the `threading` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your need is threading

```python
import threading

def do_somth()
    print("Hello World")

for i in range(10):
    threading.Thread(target=do_somth).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("list.csv")
int rows = df.shape[0]
for ind in df.index:
    if count>=rows-1:
        break
    if df[ind]['Name']=='x':
        doSomething()
    if df[ind+1]['Name']=='x':
        doSomething()
    else:
        print("Not available")
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a thread for each for isn't a good idea (if you have many rows). You can setup a thread pool using the `multiprocessing` module. Here is an example I baked up using the python 3 documentation and your code. Hope it helps. You can put your code into the `search` function. It can be done surely better, but it works and start a controlled number of threads (8 as you can see).

```
import multiprocessing
import csv


def search(cond):
    print("evaluating ", cond)


def calculate(func, args):
    result = func(*args)
    return "%s says that %s%s = %s" % (
        multiprocessing.current_process().name,
        func.__name__,
        args,
        result,
    )


def calculatestar(args):
    return calculate(*args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        TASKS = []
        with open("list.csv", "rt") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            TASKS = [(search, (row["Name"],)) for row in reader]

        results = pool.imap(calculatestar, TASKS)
        for x in results:
            print(x)
```